# Can't find beacon with altbeacon library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon

Ì am trying to connect with beacons in my android app. But I can't seem to find my beacons. I am using Ibeacons. I am using the AltBeacon Library. The onBeaconServiceConnect starts and the didDetermineStateForRegion follows. But didEnterReion never gets called. This is my code:

```
public class ListScenarios extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer, MonitorNotifier {

private static final String TAG = "ListScenarios";

private ListView listView;
public String persoonID;
public String adresID;

public Array beaconArray;
//private ArrayList<IBeacon> arrBeacons = new ArrayList<>();

private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_scenarios);

    // Setup beaconmanager
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
    // Detect iBeacon
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);



    //listview
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_scenario);

    //send request to load list
    getScenarios();
    getBeacons();



}


// MARK: - Bluetooth


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    System.out.println("We are in onBeaconServiceConnect");
    // Set the two identifiers below to null to detect any beacon regardless of identifiers
    Identifier myBeaconNamespaceId = null;
    Identifier myBeaconInstanceId = null;
    Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region", myBeaconNamespaceId, myBeaconInstanceId, null);
    mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
    try {
        mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    System.out.println("We are in didEnterRegion");
    Log.d(TAG, "I detected a beacon in the region with namespace id " + region.getId1() +
            " and instance id: " + region.getId2());
}

public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    System.out.println("We are in didExitRegion");
}

public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    System.out.println("We are in didDetermineStateForRegion");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you detect the beacon with the Locate app based on this same library? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate. What do you get for the value of `state` in `didDetermineStateForRegion`?

Comment: Yes i can find it with the locate app. And it always says 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure you are using the correct `BeaconParser` expression.   The expression shown in the question is for AltBeacon: `"m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25`.  If you are trying to detect iBeacon, you'll need to use a different expression.  This site has a handy reference: https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/
2. If you are running your app on Android 6+ and are targeting SDK 23 or higher, you need to dynamically request location permission for your app.  If you don't do this, you will get no detections, and you will see this in the logs:  `04-22 22:35:20.152  5158  5254 E BluetoothUtils: Permission denial: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results`  You can read how to do this here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it!